# Jquery text to label

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm having a really hard time with this, I found a good date range selector that uses Jquery the problem is I need to grab the text that has been output to the button so that i can query my sql database.  Im thinking the best way to do this is to output the jquery button to a label then have another button titled search that grabs the dates that have been selected. below is some of the code

```
<head>
    <link href="jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () { $("#e1").daterangepicker(); });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="e1" name="e1"><label for="no">text no</label> <<<Hoping to 
    add 
    the values from "e1 to say Value1.Text
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" name="e1">
    </asp:Label>
    </form>`
```

then when I hit search it grabs the date range and puts it into my query:

```
      protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      string testdb = 
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["easystone"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(testdb);
      SqlDataAdapter graph = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [User],  [dateof]  
      FROM [dbo].[chart]where [dateof] >='"+Label1+"' and [dateof]
      <='"+Label2+"'", 
      con);
     DataTable graphdata = new DataTable();

      graph.Fill(graphdata);

      chart1.DataSource = graphdata;


      chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "";
      }
```

`

Comment: you are missing the Question ..

Answer (score 0):

Label controls do not participate in Postbacks in the same way as input controls do, changing the value of a Label and then submitting the form will not send the Label's new value to the server.

What you can do is use a [HiddenField control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx), set its value in javascript to match the date selected in your date picker input when its value changes and then extract its value in your `Search_Click` handler.

Alternatively, you can add the `runat="server"` and `ClientIDMode="Static"` attributes to your input and then extract the value directly from the input on form submission using `e1.Value`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the alternative route?  I tried it but it isn't grabbing anything, do I need to place my search button in an update panel?